# Image height cut off in IE8

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

The logo image in the header of my client's WordPress site is displaying normally in all browsers except IE7 and IE8 - it gets cut in half (top half is not displayed).

Googling suggests an array of possible causes, from max-width to z-index. Tried everything I can find and nothing changes.

Image: http://d.pr/i/KIEA

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $data['header_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
</div>
```

Computed style (from Chrome):

```
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-border-image: none;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: #EC5923;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: #EC5923;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: #EC5923;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: #EC5923;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
color: #EC5923;
cursor: auto;
display: inline-block;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 105px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: static;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 460px;
```

Totally out of things to try.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The parent div had a negative margin which was cutting off the image.